# What goes up and down but does not move?

Tags: riddle

[image]

[image: a busy cat]
[image: two muppets]

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjE64LUm5reAhUK11MKHQkBA9YQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffreebies.com%2Friddle%2Fwhat-doesnt-move.html&psig=AOvVaw3chsBeyAh7Oy5I-VYNyCJC&ust=1540303441271264
wajbnt34yg81ot7yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyrghbfadhnvnhrhrutiog4678ghuyrhy536654tgfg

Comment: my heartbeat when I see broad riddles

Comment: oh sorry:( can people plz like and vote good things?plz:.(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a Staircase

It goes up or down but stays where it is. So does the escalator.

Comment: it is not quite an escalator but instead of taking the elavator you take the what

Comment: I think the Staircase was my primary answer in the spoiler. Thanks

Comment: wow very smart idea

Comment: um hello DEEM I'm new so could you please help me with asking the right questions:P

Comment: Hello. I think you want to ask questions (see help section) where the answers are specific and not open ended and subject to interpretation. Also "original" questions are usually appreciated much more at this  site. The question you asked was of course answered on the Net somewhere. You can always modify the concepts and start by saying " inspired by " etc. Do not be disappointed by the down votes

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate you helping me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad riddle, it could be a lot of things:

> A staircase, your opinion of someone, the value of something, the ripeness of fruit/veggies, a drawn line/graph, a mountain range, etc.

Comment: it actually is one of those things